# cross-browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, cross-browser

On the new safari browser 6.0 on Lion 10.8 this code is not executing properly. Works fine in firefox and iPad safari. But on the mac it keeps vibrating as I scroll up and down. I'm trying to keep the top banner scrolling until the button reach the top of the page at which point i want the buttons to stay fixed.

here's the link to the page:

http://www.persiantunedpiano.com/Mirror/events.htm

here's the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[

  $(document).scroll(function() {var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                        scroll(0, scrollTop);
                        if (scrollTop > 189) {
                            //alert(scrollTop);
                            $('#top_links').css('position', 'fixed');
                            $('#top_links').css('top', '0');
                            $('#left_links').css('position', 'fixed');
                            $('#left_links').css('top', '57px');


                        } else {
                            //alert('2');

                            $('#top_links').css('position','absolute');
                            $('#top_links').css('top', '186px');
                            $('#left_links').css('position', 'absolute');
                            $('#left_links').css('top', '242px');
                            //allertSize();
                        }
                        });


//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Not just on the Mac: Win7, Firefox 14, scrolls slooooooow and jerky. Also note, playing music automatically annoys some visitors (like yours truly)... `;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... seems like it is too slow, this will speed it up can't be sure it will be fast enough:

(I'm adding the jQuery elements to the closure so you don't have to search for them 4 times per move.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var top_links = $('#top_links');
  var left_links = $('#left_links');

  $(document).scroll(function() {
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     scroll(0, scrollTop);
     if (scrollTop > 189) {
       top_links.css('position', 'fixed')
                .css('top', '0');
       left_links.css('position', 'fixed')
                 .css('top', '57px');
     }
     else {
       top_links.css('position','absolute')
                .css('top', '186px');
       left_links.css('position', 'absolute')
                 .css('top', '242px');
     }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, been bogged down with other projects. Your code isn't working. Here's a page with your code: http://www.persiantunedpiano.com/Mirror/about.htm. Here's a page with the previous code which was causing the problem: http://www.persiantunedpiano.com/Mirror/events.htm. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, move my code into the `$(document).ready(function(){` function.  Worked locally for me then.

Comment: Ok. That fixed the problem. I guess this is an improvement to the previous version. However i'm still not content with the performance. It still flickers a lot when I scroll with the touchpad. Works fine when I drag the scroll bar. Just the two finger scroll doesn't work like the pre-lion safari which was completely smooth with no flicker what so ever. I'll accept your answer since it was an improvement and take that this is an issue with the new safari with no solution.